# Unreachable statement in class call in java

Tags: java, class, android-studio

I am coding in Java developing a mobile app in android studio. 
I have created a class `User`

```
package com.sourcey.materiallogindemo;

public class User {
String email;
String name ;
String mobile ;
String password ;

public User(String email, String name, String mobile, String password) {
    this.email = email;
    this.name = name;
    this.mobile = mobile;
    this.password = password;
}
```

and in the same package I needed to use this class in another class

```
{User mUser = new User(email, name, mobile, password);}
```

and an error appears:

> Delete unreachable statement

I can't understand why class user is unreachable?

Comment: Why is it in `{}` ?

Comment: What is the larger context in which you've placed that line of code?  If a line of code is unreachable, presumably the code *before* it would indicate why.

Comment: That creates `mUser` then immediately throws it away, which I presume you don't want.

Comment: Anywhere in your code (the error message will surely provide details) is a statement that is unreachable. You didn’t tell us where this error occur. But most probably it has nothing to do with class User. Normally, the IDE will tell you in what line the unreachable statement is. Let us have a look at the surroundig block.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be a problem with your `User` class. It looks like a problem in your other class you are trying to use the `User` class in.

You probably return from the method before the definition of your variable and so the lines of code are never reached. By providing the whole content of the second class I can update my answer to a more precise one.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `return` method in the affected class. It must come at the end of the method.